# list.files in R returns wildly inconsistent results

Tags: r

I hope I am not missing something obvious, but here goes. And I apologize, as I do not see how to make this reproducible.

I have over a million trail camera images (.JPG) on an external hard drive. I need to extract their filenames, recursively, which is a task I do quite regularly. It came to my attention quite accidentally, and to my horror, that list.files() is not returning identical results – in fact, the number of files returned varies from 295 to 1,214,657. In this particular case, I have  4 subfolder levels until the final .JPG files. Testing this over just 10 iterations:

```
> dir <- "/Volumes/Death_Valley_TC/Mojave_Desert_TC/"
> file.exists(dir)
[1] TRUE

> files <- list()

> for(i in 1:10){
>    files[[i]] <- list.files(dir, recursive = T)
>    print(i)
> }
```

I find:

```
> lengths(files)
[1]   85328 1214657 1214657   23429 1214657 1214657 1214657  150164     295  150164
```

If I check in bash with:

```
ls -R | wc -l
```

I get a different result: 1,218,903, which is consistent over 10 tries.

From looking at the files actually outputted at each iteration, it appears that the recursive function stalls out after completing a terminal subfolder, so perhaps it is finding its break condition prematurely?

I am working on a Mac OSX 10.13.6 with R version 4.0.0. The hard drive is a 2TB Lacie USB-C, Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled). I'm not sure what other hardware details might be relevant.

Many many thanks!

Comment: I don't have a comment on why `list.files` is failing, but you might use `system2("find", c(shQuote(dir), "-type", "f"), stdout = TRUE)` to capture all file names. (This is assuming no newlines embedded in file names ... generally safe but not pristine. If it's a concern, you might try `find ... -type f -print0` and split the output on zero-bytes.)

Comment: (BTW, this should work as-is for macos and linux, since I'm guessing that the `find` found is what I'm expecting. On windows, `find` is actually a grep-like function, so you might need to specify the full path, perhaps `"c:/Rtools/bin/find.exe"` or `"c:/Rtools40/usr/bin/find.exe"`.)

Comment: Thank you r2evans – that produced a consistent result! And taught me how to call system commands from R, which I've wondered about. Thank you. Still not the same result as from my bash script, but I presume that's from counting hidden files?

Comment: Certainly. Have you seen the output from `ls -R`? For each subdir, it includes: a blank line; the name of the subdir plus a colon; one line per file (in a pipe, might be multi-file per line if on a console). Almost certainly more "lines" than "number of files", whereas `find ... -type f` only prints one file per line for files only, no directories at all.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I hadn't checked the output. I'll use this from now on, or until I know what's going on with list.files/my use of it. Thank you so much for this @r2evans!